# Error in makefile *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: linux, makefile

The code snippet is as follows:

```
   $(shell javac $(MY_PATH)/test/TestFile.java)    

   $(shell java -cp $(MY_PATH)/test/ TestFile)
```

There is no space or tab in the start. The error i am getting is
*** missing separator. Stop.

The error is coming in second line only and not in the first line.

Basically my TestFile is not in java path.
I have tried all the solutions here but none helped me out. I guess the error has something to do with the directory path I provided. The same code snippet works with cmd prompt in windows but not in linux machine. Can't figure the exact problem. Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Why `$(shell ...)`? `$()` is supposed to execute the contained command in a shell already.

Comment: Are you really using `shell` in a recipe?

Comment: I tried with $() also but seems like the code line didn't even run as I have put some logs in the java file and those were not visible in the makefile log (The logs are visible when the error is coming)

Comment: What this supposed to do? $(shell) extracts command output, and put it where?.. (nowhere, as written - and this is an error). So question is, what you wanted to do?

Comment: I basically want to compile the java file and run it only. But the path is not included in JAVA PATH, so I was trying this way only. Sorry, but I am totally new to UNIX.

Comment: Compiling should be recipe to make TestFile.class from TestFile.java. No need for `$(shell)` or any other things. Run should be separate phony target. If you only need to execute several commands regardless of anything, you don't need make but rather just `sh` script.

Answer (score 2):

This is how makefiles supposed to be used:

```
.PHONY: run

JAVAC:=javac
JAVA:=java
TARGET:=TestFile
SOURCES:=TestFile.java
OBJS:=$(patsubst %.java, %.class, $(SOURCES))

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)

%.class: %.java
    $(JAVAC) $^

run: $(TARGET)
    $(JAVA) $(TARGET)
```

`make run` will compile and run. `make` will only compile. Of course it all could be set to one target, but better don't do that.

Comment: and if java file is present in another directory then SOURCES would be $(shell $MY_PATH/test/TestFile.java)?  And TARGET also?

Comment: `SOURCES:=$(MY_PATH)/test/testFile.java`. Told you, `$(shell)` executes separate command and gets its output so you can use it later. If you're not 100% sure you need program's output (stdout, not output files) - you don't need `$(shell)`.